# How to retrieve the clock type of std::filesystem::file_time_type in C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, c++-chrono, std-filesystem

Since [`std::filesystem::file_time_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_time_type) uses a [trivial clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TrivialClock) in C++17, is there a way to retrieve the actual clock type of `file_time_type` with C++17**?

The goal is to convert the time to [`std::chrono::system_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock) to use it e.g. in a stream.

---

** In C++20, `file_time_type` will use [`std::chrono::file_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/file_clock), which has `operator<<` and can be casted to other clocks using [`std::chrono::clock_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/clock_cast).

Comment: `file_time_type::clock`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can retrieve the clock easily enough via `file_time_type::clock`. But converting from one clock to another won't really be possible until the changes from C++20 are available.

The reason the clock even matters is that different clocks define a different "epoch" start date, the 0 time point for that clock. But in C++11-17, all clocks have an implementation-defined "epoch", and each clock can use a different one. The `file_time_type::clock` is no different. Since every implementation of every clock potentially uses a different epoch, and no clock epochs are defined relative to each other, there's no way to convert one clock's `time_point` into another clock's `time_point`. Not without implementation-specific knowledge.

C++20 changes things in exactly one way: `system_clock` has a well-defined epoch: it uses UNIX-time. Because there is one clock with a well-defined epoch, that clock can act as a universal intermediate clock for clock-to-clock conversions. That is, every implementation-defined clock's epoch can be converted relative to UNIX-time, and vice-versa. Hence: `clock_cast`.

Without that definition, and the `time_conversion` machinery, there's not much you can do... portably, at least.